# $_POST and code manipulation

Tags: php, post

I want to grab the value of a field using $_POST, manipulate it, then pass the value back to the *same* page to the *same* field **before** the PHP code manipulates it.

If I put the PHP code after the field, it manipulates the code, reloads the page but doesn't put the manipulated code back into the field.

```
    if (!isset($input)) {
        $input = '';
    }   

    echo '<form id="testform" method="post" action="">';
    echo '<input type="text" name="inputText" value="' . $input . '">';
    echo '<button type="submit" name="button"> Button </button>';
    echo '</form>';

    $input = $_POST['inputText'];

    if(isset($_POST['inputText'])) {
        $input = $input . ' manipulated';
    }

    echo $input; //test
```

If I put the PHP code before the field, it can't find the field to manipulate the value...

```
    if (!isset($input)) {
        $input = '';
    }

    $input = $_POST['inputText'];

    if(isset($_POST['inputText'])) {
        $input = $input . ' manipulated';
    }

    echo $input; //test

    echo '<form id="testform" method="post" action="">';
    echo '<input type="text" name="inputText" value="' . $input . '">';
    echo '<button type="submit" name="button"> Button </button>';
    echo '</form>';
```

Obviously the first approach is more correct, but how do I pass the `$input` variable to the field before the rest of my PHP manipulation code executes?

I tried `$_POST['inputText'] = $input` as a desperate attempt but nothing..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, from what I've understood in your explanation, you want to change the input value to something else and show it in he same field. If that's correct, you may want to do this:

```
<form id="testform" method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" name="inputText" value="<?php echo ( isset($_POST['inputText']) ) ? sprintf( '%s manipulated', $_POST['inputText'] ) : ''; ?>">
    <button type="submit"> Send </button>
</form>
```

Let me know if that's what you wanted. Regards !

Comment: Got that working but I have another issue, I will create another question.

Comment: Also this educated me in the use of the ternary operator - after some initial confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Try

`$input = isset($_POST['inputText']) ?$_POST['inputText'] :'';`

in the begining instead of

```
if (!isset($input)) {
    $input = '';
}
```

Comment: What do sessions have to do with this?

Comment: o.O that explication blown me off.

Comment: So why did you edit your answer with my solution after 12 hours ? o.O